# Domain name not found after transfer

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have moved the domain `theforcemusic.co.uk` hosted by godaddy to google cloud platform so it should point to http://35.189.90.254/ but nothing has happened.

Its nameservers are:

1. `ns-cloud-b1.googledomains.com.`
2. `ns-cloud-b2.googledomains.com.`
3. `ns-cloud-b3.googledomains.com.`
4. `ns-cloud-b4.googledomains.com.`

I notice that the last character '.' cannot be added into the nameserver field in the godaddy form.

Comment: `whois` shows the domain, and `dig theforcemusic.co.uk` shows an IP address of 35.189.90.254. That IP simply isn't responding to requests. Since you've pointed it at Google's DNS, the GoDaddy DNS forms are irrelevant now - they won't have any effect.

Comment: Last dot is not the problem, relevant DNS software can cope with it being there or not

Answer (score 2):

You are probably too impatient. The registry has correct delegation:

```
 dig theforcemusic.co.uk @nsc.nic.uk +noall +authority

 ; <<>> DiG 9.11.2 <<>> theforcemusic.co.uk @nsc.nic.uk +noall +authority
 ;; global options: +cmd
 theforcemusic.co.uk.   172800 IN NS ns-cloud-b2.googledomains.com.
 theforcemusic.co.uk.   172800 IN NS ns-cloud-b1.googledomains.com.
 theforcemusic.co.uk.   172800 IN NS ns-cloud-b4.googledomains.com.
 theforcemusic.co.uk.   172800 IN NS ns-cloud-b3.googledomains.com.
```

and Google nameservers reply correctly:

```
dig theforcemusic.co.uk @ns-cloud-b4.googledomains.com. +short
35.189.90.254
```

and same for the other 3.

So the DNS setup is OK, you may have old settings in the cache of your local recursive nameserver you will need to wait.

On the HTTP level, nothing replies at IP 35.189.90.254 port 80 so you have a configuration problem there, but this is not related to DNS.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I now have just 'hello world' where there should be a whole worpdress site.